# Оптимизация работы с json в Python

Tags: python, json, рефакторинг

Есть входящий `json(data.json)`:

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "Name": "Ivan",
        "parameter1": "XXX",
        "parameter2": 0,
        "parameter3": 0,
        "date": "2016-07-12T00:00:00",
        "parameter4": 2
    },
    {
        "Name": "Ivan",
        "parameter1": "YYY",
        "parameter2": 0,
        "parameter3": 0,
        "date": "2016-07-12T00:00:00",
        "parameter4": 2
    },
    {
        "Name": "Oleg",
        "parameter1": "XXX",
        "parameter2": 2,
        "parameter3": 3,
        "date": "2016-07-12T00:00:00",
        "parameter4": 2
    },
    {
        "Name": "Oleg",
        "parameter1": "YYY",
        "parameter2": 4,
        "parameter3": 3,
        "date": "2016-07-12T00:00:00",
        "parameter4": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

Задача спарсить этот `json(attachments.json)`, подставить значения в другой `json` для мессенджера `Slack`, чтобы потом отправить сообщением такого вида:

```
[
    {
        "fallback": "Required plain-text summary of the attachment.",
        "color": "good",
        "pretext": "мяу"
    },
    {
        "author_name": "Ivan",
        "author_icon": "http://unicodey.com/emoji-data/img-twitter-64/1f4e2.png",
        "fields": [
            {
                "title": "parameter1",
                "value": "XXX",
                "short": "true"
            },
            {
                "title": "parameter2",
                "value": "0",
                "short": "true"
            },
            {
                "title": "parameter3",
                "value": "0",
                "short": "true"
            },
            {
                "title": "parameter4",
                "value": "2",
                "short": "true"
            },
            {
                "title": "parameter1",
                "value": "YYY",
                "short": "true"
            },
            {
                "title": "parameter2",
                "value": "0",
                "short": "true"
            },
            {
                "title": "parameter3",
                "value": "0",
                "short": "true"
            },
            {
                "title": "parameter4",
                "value": "2",
                "short": "true"
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        "author_name": "Oleg",
        "author_icon": "http://unicodey.com/emoji-data/img-twitter-64/1f4e2.png",
        "fields": [
            {
                "title": "parameter1",
                "value": "XXX",
                "short": "true"
            },
            {
                "title": "parameter2",
                "value": "0",
                "short": "true"
            },
            {
                "title": "parameter3",
                "value": "0",
                "short": "true"
            },
            {
                "title": "parameter4",
                "value": "2",
                "short": "true"
            },
            {
                "title": "parameter1",
                "value": "YYY",
                "short": "true"
            },
            {
                "title": "parameter2",
                "value": "0",
                "short": "true"
            },
            {
                "title": "parameter3",
                "value": "0",
                "short": "true"
            },
            {
                "title": "parameter4",
                "value": "2",
                "short": "true"
            },
        ]
    },
```

Мой текущий вариант решения:

- создаем словарь

  ```
  Ivan = dict(xxx={'s': 0, 'c': 0, 'a': 0,},
              yyy={'s': 0, 'c': 0, 'a': 0,})
  ```
- функция парсит первый `json` и записывает нужные значения в словарь

  ```
  def get_data():
  with open('data.json', 'r') as data:
      jsonsheet = json.load(data)
  jsondata = jsonsheet["data"]
  for i in jsondata:
      if i['parameter1'] == 'XXX':
          if i['Name'] == 'Ivan':
              Ivan['xxx']['s'] = i['parameter2']
              Ivan['xxx']['c'] = i['parameter3']
              Ivan['xxx']['a'] = i['parameter4']
          elif i['parameter2'] == 'YYY':
              Ivan['yyy']['s'] = i['parameter2']
              Ivan['yyy']['c'] = i['parameter3']
              Ivan['yyy']['a'] = i['parameter4']
  ```
- функция загружает `json(attachments.json)` берет из словаря (`Ivan`) нужные значения и перезаписывает данные и возвращает `json`.

  ```
  def load_data():
  with open('attachments.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as msg:
      msgdata = json.load(msg)
  jsonmsg = msgdata[1]
  jsonmsg['fields'][2]['value'] = Ivan['parameter2']['s']
  return json.dumps(msgdata, ensure_ascii=False)
  ```

Вопросы:

1. Если вызвать `print(load_data())`, то вернется `json` с измененными значениями, однако когда я отправляю сообщение в чат, то там отдается неизмененный `json`. Почему так?
2. Во входящем json могут быть другие имена, кроме Ивана с такими же параметрами. Полагаю, что можно создать класс для такого случая, но что-то не пойму как его привязать к функции `get_data()`?
3. Есть ли более элегантное решение вместо `get_data()`?
4. Код кажется крайне большим. Возможно у кого-то есть идеи по рефакторингу?

Дополнение:
Вместо словаря решил использовать класс:

```
class Salesmanager:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.name = n
        self.xxx = ['xxx',{'sum': 0, 'chq': 0, 'avg': 0}]
        self.yyy = ['yyy',{'sum': 0, 'chq': 0, 'avg': 0}]

    def setname(self, newname):
        self.name = newname

    def set_values_d(self, s, c, a):
        self.xxx[1]['sum'] = s
        self.xxx[1]['chq'] = c
        self.xxx[1]['avg'] = a

    def set_values_nd(self, s, c, a):
        self.yyy[1]['sum'] = s
        self.yyy[1]['chq'] = c
        self.yyy[1]['avg'] = a

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Имя: {0}\n''xxx: {1}\n''yyy: {2}'. \
            format(self.name, self.xxx, self.yyy)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если правильно понял задачу то, вот:

```
import json
from datetime import datetime

input_json = """{
"data": [
    {
        "Name": "Ivan",
        "parameter1": "XXX",
        "parameter2": 0,
        "parameter3": 0,
        "date": "2016-07-12T00:00:00",
        "parameter4": 2
    },
    {
        "Name": "Ivan",
        "parameter1": "YYY",
        "parameter2": 0,
        "parameter3": 0,
        "date": "2016-07-12T00:00:09",
        "parameter4": 2
    }
  ]
}"""

def get_data(json_string):
  # я использую loads(-tring) по тому что у меня строка, если вы принимаете
  # .json используйте load
  json_string = json.loads(json_string)

  # словарь это не сортированный массив данных, и если порядок важен, то
  # его нужно отсортировать, и сделаем мы это по полю дата.

  # я не знаю в каком формате тут дата гггг-мм-дд или гггг-дд-мм
  # точно также как и не знаю часы в 12 или 24 формате (хотя скорее всего 24).
  # в случае если будут ощибки то маску можешь собрать сам
  # по этой таблице: 
  # https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

  json_string['data'] = sorted(json_string['data'], 
    key=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x['date'], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'))

  output_json = {
      "author_name": "Ivan",
      "author_icon": "link_to_img",
      "fields": list()
    }

  for msg in json_string['data']:
    # ну я так понимаю дату ты не передаешь, так что она нам не нужна, 
    # как и имя.
    del msg['date'], msg['Name']

    for parameter, value in msg.items():
      output_json['fields'].append({
        "title": parameter, "value": value, "short": True
      })

  return json.dumps(output_json)

print(get_data(input_json))
```

Это конечно не финальная версия а реализация вот этого блока:

```
{
    "author_name": "Ivan",
    "author_icon": "link_to_img",
    "fields": [
        {
            "title": "parameter1",
            "value": "XXX",
            "short": "true"
        }
    ]
}
```

#### Если я не совсем правильно понял задание, отпишись, поправлю реализацию.

Comment: json я получаю по url. Работа с файлами была сделана для удобства(чтобы не делать запросы каждые 2 минуты). Далее полученые данные мне надо подставлять в нужные места attachments.json и отправлять в чат. Я поправил свой вопрос(добавил класс).

Comment: Хоть убейте класс не вижу. И совсем не понимаю зачем именно он нужен. Стреляете из базуки по одноклеточным, голубчик.

Comment: Класс пока не добавлял. Там чтобы все понять надо функцию переписывать, но она еще не готова) Почему класс:
во входящем json будут Иваны, Пети, Зины(всего 3). Чтобы не записывать их всех каждый раз в словарь я подумал, что можно создавать объект класса на основе данных входящего json, а потом из этого класса забирать значения для исходящего json. Это не правильно?

Comment: Так у тебя же есть имя в json'e зачем тебе писать их в словарь? Бери имя из входящего json'a и все. Как я сказал та функция что я написал почти полностью возвращает готовый json который ты просил, за исключением параметров которые ты не рассказал откуда берутся.

Comment: Напиши ка здесь входной и выходной json'ы с двумя людьми.
https://codeshare.io/893d8

Comment: Залил по ссылке.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42824/discussion-between-dmitryc-and-vasiliy-rusin).